# python call set property when property missing

Tags: python

I have an object that has several properties containing values that take a while to query. so I dont want to get all the values for those properties when I create the instance, but just when the code path actually requires the property as only a few are needed depending on the code path. The order when I reach certain points int eh code is also not very deterministic, so I cant set the property at a fixed point in the script. So I was going to create a method

```
def getValue(self, attributeName):
    if hasattr(self, attributeName): 
        return getattr(self, attributeName)
    elif attributeName == 'A1':
        v = ... code to get value for A1
        self.A1 = v
        return v
    elif attributeName == 'A2':
        v = ... code to get value for A2
        self.A2 = v
        return v
    ....
```

But I was wondering if this is actually a good way to deal with this or if there are some smarter ways that would be preferred.
Thanks for any comment

Comment: Use these: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this decorator:

```
class cached_property(object):
    """Define property caching its value on per instance basis.
    Decorator that converts a method with a single self argument into a
    property cached on the instance.
    """
    def __init__(self, method):
        self.method = method

    def __get__(self, instance, type):
        res = instance.__dict__[self.method.__name__] = self.method(instance)
        return res
```

[Here](http://ericplumb.com/blog/understanding-djangos-cached%5fproperty-decorator.html) is an explanation.

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand this. How would that class interact with my object?

Comment: use this decorator to decorate methods of a class. for example `@cached_property; def A1(self):`. Then you will get the behavior you described. You can decorate as many methods as you want, without the need to fiddle with `try: except AttributeError:` in each of them

Comment: This decorator creates cached properties using the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html)

Comment: I am not sure I follow the' __get__'-part. do you overwrite the method with the value so that on any subsequent call of the method, it will return the value without executing the method that queries it anymore?

Comment: yes, exactly. I found this pattern on Internet, but cannot find the source

Comment: Here it is: http://ericplumb.com/blog/understanding-djangos-cached_property-decorator.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. Seems to be exactly my use case

Answer (score 1):

You can use [python properties](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) like this:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        # ordinary attributes
        self.B1 = something
        self.B2 = something_else

    @property
    def A1(self):
        try:
            return self._A1
        except AttributeError:
            self._A1 = ....calculate it....
            return self._A1
```

Then you can:

```
foo = Foo()
print foo.A1  # attribute calculated when first used
print foo.A1  # this time, the value calculated before is used
```

Comment: Thanks, that sounds exactly like what I was looking for